# In Illustrator, how do I paste in place one object on multiple artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My file has multiple artboards and I need to copy an object on one artboard and paste it in the same place on all the other artboards.

My co-worker showed me it once and I didn't write it down!

Answer (score 8):

Select the object.

Choose `Edit > Cut` (yes, use cut. It will copy the object and remove it from the current artboard. This is what you want)

Now choose `Edit > Paste on All Artboards`

That will paste the object on *all* artboards, including the one you removed it from, in the same relative position on the artboard.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Press "ctrl+c" after "alt+ctrl+shift+v" to paste same object on multiple artboard at same time

Comment: Yes, but technically the question has been answered already. This shortcut does the same thing Scott said in 2015: running the Edit > Paste on All Artboards menu item.